# how to convert string with hexadecimal characters transformed into a list of hexadecimal integers

Tags: python, string, list, integer, hex

I'm trying to create a list of hexadecimal integers from a string of hexadecimal digits.

```
string = '000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f101112131415161718191a1b1c1d1e1f'
```

Comment: What is your required output?

Answer (score 0):

did you mean this?

```
string = '000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f101112131415161718191a1b1c1d1e1f'
print(list(string))
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess all you need to do is split after 2 characters.

```
string = '000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f101112131415161718191a1b1c1d1e1f'
n = 2
l = [string[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(string), n)]
```

To convert it to an integer use

```
l = [int(string[i:i + n], 16) for i in range(0, len(string), n)]
```